# Django: Changing model attributes via shell creates an empty copy of said model, but doesn't change original

Tags: django

```
from app.models import Person
person = Person.objects.get(name='Carl')
person.name = 'John'
person.save()
```

Now, there is a new, empty `Person` entry in the database with the name John, but none of the other attributes that 'Carl' has (age, address, etc.). Furthermore, the original Carl object isn't changed at all.

How can I just *change* what the person's `name` attribute is?

Comment: What you describe is not the behaviour of this code.

Comment: This doesnt seem like normal behavior - a new instance should only be created when calling an existing instance's `.save` if you clear out the pk first, e.g. `person.id = None; person.save()`   Can you share the code for your person model?

Comment: @Joseph In the code above, I *am* calling an existing instance's `save` method (the existing instance is the Person who's name attribute is Carl).

Comment: But doing that does not give the result you claim. You at least need to show your models.

Comment: @amagicalfishy there was a qualifier on my statement: "if you clear out the pk first". You are not clearing out the pk in the code you showed, therefore a new instance should not be created and instead the existing instance will be updated. This is Django's normal behavior. If you are getting different results, there must be something else going on.